# Draw CSS3 matrix3D to a canvas 2D element

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, transform

I would like to know if there's a way to draw an image into a canvas using a CSS3 Matrix3D transformation. The used context is a `2D` one used to render stacked layers and an image layer transformed with a `matrix3D` above it (because I didn't manage to have it drawn in the canvas).

So basically what I want to achieve is to convert `transform: matrix3d(0.87, 0, 0.5, -0.00025, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0.87, 0, 0, 550, 0, 1)` into a drawing canvas method in a 2D context.

Is it possible ? For now, I'm quite fine with the CSS3 layer above the canvas but the application I'm developing will have to export the canvas to an actual image file (meant to be sent to the user).

Here's a snippet illustrating my current way of displaying the transformed layer. So the goal here is to actually render the "placeholder" transformed image into the canvas

```css
#canvas {
  background: tomato;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

.viewport .transformed-layer {
    height: 72%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    top: calc(21% - 550px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1.5deg) matrix3d(0.87, 0, 0.5, -0.00025, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0.87, 0, 0, 550, 0, 1);
    transform: rotate(-1.5deg) matrix3d(0.87, 0, 0.5, -0.00025, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0.87, 0, 0, 550, 0, 1);
    opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<div class='viewport'>
  <div id='canvas'>This is a div simulating the canvas element with some drawed image</div>
  <img class='transformed-layer' src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x300' />
</div>
```

Comment: The canvas context has a 2D in its name for a reason. The answer is no you can not use a 3D transform on the 2D canvas.

Comment: Thank you for your input. CSS is used in a 2D context too (even if it's not explicit) and yet, the matrix3D is available as it fakes 3D behavior. I was just wondering if there was something similar for 2D canvas.

Comment: Nothing fake about a 3D transform, and no there is no native API for 3D rendering in the 2D context. You can do it in javascript (the rendering that is) but it will be pixel by pixel and slow. If you want 3D on the canvas just use webGL.

Comment: I was not especially asking for a native way to do that as I figured out there is none... But I cannot find an existing lib that could "translate" the matrix3D into a 2D canvas version. I guess I'll have to consider writing it myself then. I also considered the [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations) method but it's not as complete as the matrix3D css.

Answer (score 4):

There is one heck of hack that may not fit any future-readers requirements, but which may do for you:

The canvas can draw SVG images, and SVG images can be transformed via CSS.
So you could convert your current canvas to a dataURL, set this dataURL as the href of an SVGImage element, on which you would apply the CSSTransform, before exporting all this as an svg image that you'll draw back on a canvas.

Here is a rough proof of concept:

```js
function getTransformedCanvas(canvas, CSSTransform){
  return new Promise(function(res, rej){
    var dim = getTransformedDimensions(canvas, CSSTransform);
    var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
        svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    var svg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'svg'),
      defs = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'defs'),
      style = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'style'),
    image = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'image');
    image.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, 'href', canvas.toDataURL());
    image.setAttribute('width', canvas.width);
    image.setAttribute('height', canvas.height);
    style.innerHTML = 'image{transform:'+CSSTransform+';}';
    svg.appendChild(defs);
    defs.appendChild(style);
    var rect = document.createElement('rect');

    svg.appendChild(image);
    svg.setAttribute('width', dim.width);
    svg.setAttribute('height', dim.height);
    var svgStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){res(img)};
    img.onerror = rej;
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([svgStr], {type:'image/svg+xml'}));
  });
}

function getTransformedDimensions(canvas, CSSTransform){
  var orphan = !canvas.parentNode;
  if(orphan) document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  var oldTrans = getComputedStyle(canvas).transform;
  canvas.style.transform = CSSTransform;
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.style.transform = oldTrans;
  if(orphan) document.body.removeChild(canvas);
  return rect;
 }

// create a simple checkerboard
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 30;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,15, 15);
ctx.fillRect(15,15,15, 15);
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(canvas, 'repeat');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 300;
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
getTransformedCanvas(canvas, 
 'translateY(-540px) rotate(-1.5deg) matrix3d(0.87, 0, 0.5, -0.00025, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0.87, 0, 0, 550, 0, 1)'
 )
 .then(function(img){
  inScreen.width = img.width;
  inScreen.height = img.height;
  inScreen.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0,0);
  })
.catch(console.error);
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="inScreen"></canvas>
```

But note that old versions of IE did taint the canvas whenever an svg iamge was drawn on it...

Comment: Oh ! I absolutely didn't thought about svg embed css. I will try this today or tomorrow and give you my feedback. Already upvoted as the concept totally adresses my issue. Thanks already !

Comment: Didn't work that well for me ! Thank you for taking the time to show me this lead. Some `matrix3d` are working on chrome but not all of them. On Firefox and Safari, no image is rendered at all. So I guess I am going to go for either a backend solution or a simple canvas transform.